# how to include authenticated user's roles in JWT?

Tags: cas, apereo

i have configured CAS as OAuth2 server. After successfull login, it returns JWT, but roles field in JWT is always empty like;

```
{
"sub": "dg",
...
"roles": [],
"nonce": "",
"client_id": "first-client",
"credentialType": "UsernamePasswordCredential",
...

}
```

how can fetch and put authenticated user's role in JWT when i login?

here is my sample service registry;

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "http://localhost:8085/.*",
  "name" : "CAS Spring Secured App",
  "description": "This is a Spring App that usses the CAS Server for its authentication",
  "id" : 1,
  "evaluationOrder" : 1,
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
  "jwtAccessToken": true,
  "clientId": "first-client",
  "clientSecret": "noonewilleverguess",
  "supportedGrantTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "authorization_code" ] ],
  "supportedResponseTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "code" ] ]
}
```

thanks for helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution. From CAS blog (https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/22/cas51-dbauthn-tutorial/),

> Today, CAS is unable to retrieve attributes as part of authentication directly so we need to set up a separate attribute repository instance that CAS will contact once the user is fully authenticated.

So, we need to use attribute repository (which has many types like ldap, jdbc, stub ... https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/configuration/Configuration-Properties.html#stub)

I have configured jdbc for attribute repository. (postgresql as database)

First of all, you need to add two dependencies to build.gradle

```
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-jdbc:${casServerVersion}"
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-jdbc-drivers:${casServerVersion}"
```

then, create database where you fetch attributes. for example, named my_roles

```
id (serial) | user_name (varchar(50)) | role_name (text[])
----------------------------------------------------------
    1       |       dg                | {'ROLE_READ', 'ROLE_WRITE'}
```

then, configure attribute repository like this

```
cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].sql=SELECT * FROM my_roles WHERE {0}
cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].username=user_name

cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].user=postgres
cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].password=postgres
cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer
cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
cas.authn.attribute-repository.jdbc[0].dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

lastly, dont forget to add release policy to your service registry.

```
{
  ...
  "attributeReleasePolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllowedAttributeReleasePolicy",
    "allowedAttributes" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ "role_name" ] ]
  }
}
```

so, here is the result;

```
{
  "sub": "dg",
   ...
  "role_name":
  [
    "ROLE_WRITE",
    "ROLE_READ"
  ],
  "aud": "http://localhost:8085/login/oauth2/code/login-client",
  "grant_type": "AUTHORIZATION_CODE",
  ...
}
```